# Spring cloud contract stub runner - finding stub jar from single executable Spring Boot app jar

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a valid spring cloud contract stub jar generated by spring rest docs and wire mock rest docs.

when I have the stub jar installed in local maven repo, stub runner application can successfully find and load the stub jar and deploy contracts.

However, in order to eliminate maven dependancy, I would like to run the stub runner as a single executable jar file containing the stub jar as well. In that case, the stub runner CAN NOT find and load the stub jar and deploys an empty set of stubs.

Here is the Java code that starts the stub runner

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableStubRunnerServer
public class AppApiStubRunner {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppApiStubRunner.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the application.proerpties file defining the stub ids

```
stubrunner.work-offline=true
stubrunner.ids=com.example:producer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:9111
```

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the classifier I guess... `stubrunner.ids=com.example:producer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:9111` should be `stubrunner.ids=com.example:producer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:stubs:9111`